# How to create a custom display mode for user in D8?

Tags: views, users

I've created an edito custom content type wich can be linked to a user. I'd like to custom the display with the picture and the name of the user in a view. I don't know how to create a custom display mode for an user.

Any help ?²

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the view mode at Admin > Structure > Display Modes, then configure the new display mode at `/admin/config/people/accounts/display`.